# How to import data from csv file into my table in Sqlite3 using Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, csv, import

I want to import all data(around 200 000 rows) from csv file (which has **4 columns**) into already created table (table has **5 columns**) in **sqlite3** database using Python (Pandas dataframe). Data types in csv and table satisfy with each other. Problem is that, in the table there is a one extra column which is `index_of(Primary Key)`.

**These are the first 3 lines of my csv file:**

[image]

That's all I could do, I guess if it will work, it takes about 5-6 hours, because in this code I used for loop to read every row:

```py
connection = _sqlite3.connect("db_name.sqlite")
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open('path_to_csv', 'r') as file:
    no_records = 0
    for row in file: 
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (index_of, high, low, original, ship_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", row.split(","))
        connection.commit()
        no_records += 1  
        
connection.close()
```

but it shows me an error: **Exception has occurred: OperationalError
5 values for 4 columns**

Please, can you help me with this:

1. How to import 200 000 rows fast using Python?
2. How to import all columns from csv file into the table's specific columns?

Answer (score 1):

user3380595 has already pointed out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700488/42659) that you need to provide a value for the column `index_of`.

```py
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO Quotes (index_of, high, low, original, ship_date)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """, [index, *row])
```

I created 200,000 lines of test data and it loaded quite fast (less than 2 seconds). See first example using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

As user3380595 mentioned, you could load the data in chunks if you are concerned about memory and performance. This scenario was actually loaded slightly slower. See second example using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [`sqlalchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

---

**Using `csv` and `sqlite3`**

Setup Test Environment

```py
import csv
import sqlite3
import contextlib

import pandas as pd

test_data = r"/home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.csv"
test_db = r"/home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.db"

with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(test_db)) as connection:
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Quotes;")

    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Quotes (
            index_of INTEGER, -- PRIMARY KEY,
            high REAL,
            low REAL,
            original REAL,
            ship_date TEXT
        );
        """)

    connection.commit()
```

Load Data

```py
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(test_db)) as connection:
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with open(test_data, "r") as file:
        
        for index, row in enumerate(csv.reader(file)):
            cursor.execute("""
                INSERT INTO Quotes (index_of, high, low, original, ship_date)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                """, [index, *row])

    connection.commit()
```

---

**Using `pandas` and `sqlalchemy`**

Setup Test Environment

```py
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

test_data = r"/home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.csv"
test_db = r"sqlite:////home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.db"

engine = create_engine(test_db, echo=True)

with engine.begin() as connection:

    engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Quotes;")

    engine.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Quotes (
            index_of INTEGER, -- PRIMARY KEY,
            high REAL,
            low REAL,
            original REAL,
            ship_date TEXT
        );
        """)
```

Load Data (in chunks)

```py
with engine.begin() as connection:

    reader = pd.read_csv(test_data, iterator=True, chunksize=50000)

    for chunk in reader:
        chunk["index_of"] = chunk.index
        chunk.to_sql("Quotes", con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

---

Alternatively, instead of using `pandas`, you could also use [`sqlite3.Cursor.executemany`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) and process chunks of rows.

---

Or, you could use [`dask.dataframe.to_sql`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.to_sql.html) (example assumes an existing database with a table Quotes) and write the data parallel. However, I don't think it's needed with your data.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

test_data = r"/home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.csv"
test_db = r"sqlite:////home/thomas/Projects/Playground/stackoverflow/data/test.db"

df = dd.read_csv(test_data)  # , blocksize=2e6
df["index_of"] = df.index
df.to_sql("Quotes", uri=test_db, if_exists="append", index=False, parallel=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a default value for the 5th column.

You could also improve the performance of the script if you insert chunks of 100-200 rows in each SQL sentence.